# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger - Eclipse still searching for old class after upgrading from version 1 to 2.17.0

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j, executable-jar

I am working on a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and I have recently upgraded log4j from version 1 to the latest version i.e 2.17.0. I have also made all the changes in code according to new Jar file.

Now I am facing a strange issue, whenever I try to download a pdf, it throws this exception

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger"

I am using the log.4j library in a lot of different places and it's working fine. Except for this one place where the code tries to find the old class of log4j.

Here's my code, it is throwing an error on this line "PDDocument.load(f);"

```
public static boolean merge(List<File> PDFFiles, File targetFile){
    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
    ut.setDestinationFileName(targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
    for (File f : PDFFiles) {
        try {
            PDDocument.load(f);
            ut.addSource(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            lgr.error(e);

        }
        
    }
    try {
        ut.mergeDocuments();
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        lgr.error(e);

        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        lgr.error(e);

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like your imports are incorrect, since v2 it should be import `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;` I believe.